# How can I do programmatically gradient border color UIButton with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, swift2, gradient

How can I design programmatically UIButton like this gradient border color?

[image: Gradient button]]

Thanks for help

Comment: I need gradient border color pls click to link : )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193993/how-to-make-a-gradient-border-of-uiview   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200814/how-to-set-a-gradient-border-on-uiview , follow this link

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.myButton.frame.size)
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor]

let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.lineWidth = 2
shape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.myButton.bounds).CGPath
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
shape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
gradient.mask = shape

self.myButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

**Swift 3** version:

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.myButton.frame.size)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.myButton.bounds).cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradient.mask = shape

    self.myButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: It works, but is it possibly to make the corners rounded instead of being pointy ?

Comment: @Ahmad you can use the cornerRadius property

Comment: to add corner radius 
        shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.myButton.bounds, cornerRadius: self.myButton.cornerRadius).cgPath

Comment: And don't forget to add `self.myButton.clipsToBounds = true` for correct corner radius showing

Comment: To add corner radius in Swift 4.2 + , use following code: `myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myButton.bounds, cornerRadius: myButton.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath` The `cornerRadius` is the attribute of layer and not of UIButton.

Comment: how to add shadows to the gradient border views

Comment: why everyone hardcodes layer sizes on creation? People can't just take and use your code without of significant modifications