# Zeplin Inside Borders to iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, zeplin

I am struggling with extracting the code from the given inputs on Zeplin design. Zeplin shows me borders with inside of two dimension with each dimension having 4 different color. To be honest, I couldn't understand what does 4 different color means in terms of border. And also, that causes me to cannot create a proper inside border.

Beside, I understand the border axises for X and Y, but I even couldn't figure out how to give only top border and not giving for bottom (like a one side border)

You can find the specifications of the borders at the image below.

[image: An example Zeplin output for inside border]

I would be glad if you can provide me an example with a code (both for Swift and Obj-C are okay) or I am also okay for any advices through an explanation of the different coloring.

Comment: I think they want you to create a gradient border. 4 Colors mean that you have gradient consisting of these 4 colors. To implement this you would need to create a CAGradientLayer.

Comment: The solution might be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836367/how-can-i-do-programmatically-gradient-border-color-uibutton-with-swift

Comment: there is only one color with 4 different opacity,like alpha.

Comment: So, that makes sense. I am giving a try to create gradient border. Thanks!