# How to apply gradient border color to UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, gradient

I want to achieve something like this. I have searched for this. I get suggestions that I can put a gradient view behind the button with height and width more than the button. But I want exact corner radius and border color with gradients.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836787

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own `BorderedButton` subclass that will:

- Add gradient sublayer;
- Create shape layer consisting of the path of the border; And
- Use that shape layer as mask to the gradient layer to yield gradient border in the shape of the path.

E.g.:

```
@IBDesignable
class BorderedButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth:    CGFloat = 3  { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    let borderLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let borderLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        borderLayer.type = .axial
        borderLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.6135130525, green: 0.3031745553, blue: 0.9506058097, alpha: 1).cgColor, #colorLiteral(red: 0.9306473136, green: 0.1160953864, blue: 0.8244602084, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        borderLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        borderLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        return borderLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        borderLayer.frame = bounds

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)
        mask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        mask.lineWidth = lineWidth
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        mask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        borderLayer.mask = mask
    }
}

private extension BorderedButton {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
}
```

Note that:

- I update the `frame` of the gradient layer and the path that is used as the `mask` inside the `layoutSubviews` method, which ensures that the border is correctly rendered if the size changes (e.g. you’re using constraints to define the size of the view).
- I’ve made this `@IBDesignable` so that you can even add this to a storyboard and you’ll see it rendered correctly.
- I’ve made the `cornerRadius` and `lineWidth` to be `@IBInspectable` so that you can adjust these in IB (and because they have `didSet` observers that sets “needs layout”, they’ll ensure that changes are observable in the storyboard).

Anyway, that yields:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
extension CALayer {
    func addGradienBorder(colors:[UIColor],width:CGFloat = 1) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map({$0.CGColor})

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer

        self.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
```